# Directive to load different templates according to the model value received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-model

I'm writing a directive that consists of an inline editor. When there is no value the edit box will appear. When there is value a regular span will appear.

This is the template chunk of the directive.

```
template: function (element,attrs) {

    if (1 === 2) {
        return "<div class='true'>{{product.title}}</div>";
    } else {
        return "<div class='false'>{{product.title}}</div>";
    }

}
```

The above code works, but the condition will be based on the model value received, I passed,  `ngModel`, previously but it didn´t work:

```
require: '?ngModel',

template: function (element,attrs,ngModel) {

    if (ngModel.$modelValue !== null) {
        return "<div class='true'>{{product.title}}</div>";
    } else {
        return "<div class='false'>{{product.title}}</div>";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div inline-editor ng-model="product.title"></div>
```

How do I get an AngularJS directive to load a different template based on a model value?

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone for your answers!, I took your comments, now I have the following code. Working for me until now, I will continue working on it.

```
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        if (!ngModel) return;       

        //Formatter
        function writeElement (value) {

            var template;

            if (value !== null) {
                template = "<span>" + value + "</span>";
            } else {
                //template for false
            }

            element.replaceWith(template);
        }

        ngModel.$formatters.push(writeElement);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic does not belong in the `template` function, I think, but in the `template` itself:

```
template:
  '<div class="true"  ng-if="product.title == null">{{product.title}}</div>' +
  '<div class="false" ng-if="product.title != null">{{product.title}}</div>'
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea, `inline-editor` assumes `product.title` is on the outer scope. You can not reuse this directive.

Comment: @IlanFrumer This was an example derived from original code. It deals with only the question of how to pick _a template_.

Answer (score 3):

#### There are some problems with your code:

- You cannot put `ng-model` on a div tag.
- directive's template function signature is `function(tElement, tAttrs) {` , basically it runs during the compile phase and the ngModelController is not available yet.
- You refer an outer scope variable `{{ product.title }}` inside your directive which couples your directive with the outer scope.
- You don't need to use 2 classes  ( *true* / *false* )

From [ngModel docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel):

> The ngModel directive binds an **input,select, textarea (or custom form control)** to a property on the scope using **ngModelController**, which is created and exposed by this directive.

From [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile):

> **template**
>
> replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one. See the Directives Guide for an example.
>
> You can specify template as a string representing the template or as **a function which takes two arguments tElement and tAttrs** (described in the compile function api below) and returns a string value representing the template.

#### An example of how you can do it:

a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UPbLXoucVCQXvPmm6BuZ?p=preview

**Directive:**

```js
app.directive('inlineEditor',function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {
      model: "=ngModel"
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    compile: function(tElm,tAttrs) {
      var editor = angular.element("<div ng-class='{showEditor: model}'>{{model}}</div>");
      var linkFn = $compile(editor);
      return function (scope,elm,attrs,ngModel){
        linkFn(scope);
        elm.after(editor);
      }      
    }
  }
})
```

**css:**

```css
.showEditor {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**html:**

```html
<input inline-editor ng-model="product.title">
```

Comment: "You cannot put ng-model on a div tag". This isn't accurate: you can certainly put an ng-model on a div tag. You might want to do this when creating a custom form control, as mentioned by the docs you've quoted.